# To remove the key from dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
def length_words(new):
    a = ",.!?'"
    for a in new:
        b = new.replace(a,"")
    b = b.lower()
    b = b.split()

    d = []
    for i in b:
        c = len(i)
        d.append(c)
    d.sort()
    e = d[-1]
    f = d[0]

    new2 = {}
    for i in range(f,e+1):
        new2[i] = []
    for i in range(1,e+1):
        for j in b:
            if len(j) == i:
                new2[i].append(j)

    for word in new2:
        if len(new2[word]) == 0:
            del new2[word]
    return new2
```

print(length_words("If I don’t like something, I’ll stay away from it."))

The solution must have the dictionary : {1: ['i'], 2: ['if', 'it'], 4: ['like', 'i’ll', 'stay', 'away', 'from'], 5: ['don’t'], 9: ['something']}
I have done the program for that, but when i try to run, it displays ***"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"***
Hpw do i delete the key with the empty list?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you cannot delete keys from a dictionary while iterating on its keys. I replaced the last block in your function with a dict comprehension.

```
def length_words(new):
    a = ",.!?'"
    for a in new:
        b = new.replace(a,"")
    b = b.lower()
    b = b.split()

    d = []
    for i in b:
        c = len(i)
        d.append(c)
    d.sort()
    e = d[-1]
    f = d[0]

    new2 = {}
    for i in range(f,e+1):
        new2[i] = []
    for i in range(1,e+1):
        for j in b:
            if len(j) == i:
                new2[i].append(j)
    # Create a new dict that has only the keys with a value that its length is bigger than 0
    new2 = {k: v for k, v in new2.items() if len(v) > 0}
    return new2
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to python, I haven't started with the dictionary comprehension kinds of stuff. Is it possible if I could delete the keys after the iteration is over?

Comment: You can iterate on the keys, keep the keys that you would like to delete inside a list and then iterate on them and delete each. But why? Edit: I have seen that its because you consider yourself a beginner, but I would advise you to invest the little time it requires to learn it. It is very Pythonic and useful.

Comment: Okay fine. I have to learn the comprehension later on in my class. So I can't use them right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
def length_words(new):
    a = ",.!?'"
    for a in new:
        b = new.replace(a,"")
    b = b.lower()
    b = b.split()

    d = []
    for i in b:
        c = len(i)
        d.append(c)
    d.sort()
    e = d[-1]
    f = d[0]

    new2 = {}
    for i in range(f,e+1):
        new2[i] = []
    for i in range(1,e+1):
        for j in b:
            if len(j) == i:
                new2[i].append(j)

    for word in list(new2.keys()):
        if len(new2[word]) == 0:
            del new2[word]
    return new2
```

Deletion or insertions are not allowed when you are iterating through dictionary.
To do this you need to get the keys first and then iterate through the dictionary using these keys which was done using list(new2.keys())